# Is there any way to use SQL Views in Drupal Views

Tags: views, database

I have some very tricky reports to develop (with multiple subqueries) and it occurred to me that the Data module would be perfect: I can create my complex queries as SQL Views (I know how to do this), then adopt them with Data and use them as ordinary tables in Views. Perfect!

Except that although you can adopt a SQL View, it won't show up in Drupal Views (apparently because no primary key) and of course you can't add a primary key to a SQL View.

Is there any way round this by using a module to replace the View SQL query? I have searched a lot on the web and cannot get around the problem without coding object PHP which to be honest I find intimidating.

Comment: It might be a bit tricky, but it sounds like perhaps patching the data module to allow you to add a primary key might help? Have you checked the issue queue if anyone has already tried?

Comment: Looks like [someone else has made an attempt in this direction](https://www.drupal.org/node/1973806) but to be honest I was hoping to avoid this because I don't understand at all how Views works from the inside, and I was a bit daunted by the idea of trying to understand the Views API. I don't even know where to begin on this.

Comment: I no little knowledge of how Views works in the inside, but the api for telling Views about tables is fairly straightforward in my opinion. There's also plenty of examples of it around. I'd probably try going down that route.

Comment: Fiddling around, I managed through a very simple modification in data_ui to "trick" it into thinking that the View was a data table. Then somehow adding a "real" table caused my SQL View to show up in the content list of Views, and i could list content! But I haven't been able to reproduce the "trick" - still I think you're right this is probably the way to go. And it could be a real addition to Views too - the possibilities are practically endless if you could make really complex queries be treated as if they were simple tables!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know your use-case. But look at new [Raw SQL Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/raw_sql_query) module, and see its attached screenshost(s) for how you define the `SELECT queries` and the report pages it generates:

> It builds "tables" (mysql views using "CREATE VIEW" statement) based
>   on raw sql queries. I would say it is like a lightweight version of a
>   materialized views approach. It uses Ctools to manage data storage and
>   PHPExcel to export data into a Excel file :) After installation, go to
>   admin/config/development/raw_sql_query Do not forget clean cache after
>   you store a query.

It sounds like this module is caching the returned data (I'm not 100% sure). But that would be helpful since a mysql view is literally a `SELECT` query upon every access to the data.